# How to clone a Linux server on EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cloning

Hi have a linux server on EC2 and I created a snapshot from that server, the the snapshot has been used to create an AMI, then I created an instance from the AMI. I always get a file system error, cannot mount the file system.

How can I start a new EC2 instance with the data I have in the other server? For data I mean the whole server's EBS, apache, its configuration, its virtual sites and sites' data

Comment: The procedure you have is correct and accomplish what you want. However, you probably need to edit your /etc/fstab - remove any entries for mounted volumes (other than root, of course). EBS volumes, and unavailable ephemeral storage typically cause that error. Alternatively, if you use multiple EBS volumes, you will need to specify snapshots of them in the register/run command, so that they can be attached on launch.

Comment: but if the new instance never gets ready, how can I connect to it and modify /etc/ftab?

Comment: You stop the instance, detach the EBS volume, start a new instance (that doesn't use that EBS volume), attach the EBS volume as an additional device, SSH into the new instance, mount the EBS volume, make your changes, unmount the volume, detach the volume, attach it to the original instance, start the original instance and if all is well, terminate the new instance. (You may also wish to see [this article](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root), from Alestic)

Comment: @cyberx86, I can't tell you how much I appreciate that tip.  It seems obvious now, but was not well documented anywhere I found.